# asp.net sql server error messages

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have developed a modelling system using SQL Server with an ASP.NET(VB) front end.

The front end is used for data inputs and some pretty meaty procedures are run in SQL Server Management Studio to run the calculations.

However the system is going to be productionalised and i am going to lose access to the Live backend. Therefore the procedures will need to be run from the ASP.NET site.

My concern is that i will not be able to track any errors that occur in the calculations.

Is there a way to display these errors &/or any message updates that currently display when the SQL Server procedures are run in SSMS on an ASP.NET webpage?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should introduce proper error handling.

You can use additional libraries like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to write error to a file, or any other source.

Also .NET has a built-in mechanism to retrieve latest errors (Trace.axd).

You can find more info on ASP.NET Tracing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx).

Comment: @user2417642: need more help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is right way but I am doing like that.

create a function like:

```
        //Log error
    static public void logError(Exception erorr)
    {
        //create/append file with current date as file name
        string logfile = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log";
        logfile = Global.logpath + logfile; //logpath is a full folder path defined it the Global.cs file to hold the log files.
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(logfile))
        {
            sw.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            sw.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            sw.WriteLine("  :");
            sw.WriteLine("  :Message :{0}", erorr.Message);
            sw.WriteLine("  :Source  :{0}", erorr.Source);
            if (erorr.InnerException != null)
                sw.WriteLine("  :Inner Ex:{0}", erorr.InnerException.Message);

            System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(erorr, true);
            var stackFrame = trace.GetFrame(trace.FrameCount - 1);
            sw.WriteLine("  :");
            sw.WriteLine("  :Stack   :");
            sw.WriteLine("           :Line Number :{0}", stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber());
            sw.WriteLine("           :Source File :{0}", stackFrame.GetFileName());
            sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }
    }
```

then put your calculation in a `try ... catch` block. Like

```
try 
{
  //do my sql....
  //.............
{
catch(Exception ex)
{
   logError(ex);
}
```

To view the log in asp.net.
Create a page and read the logfile.

NB: I will be happy to see the comments from expert about this approach.
Thanks
Happy Coding :)